# Elasticsearch "max_ngram_diff" working for "edge_ngram" but not for "ngram_tokenizer"

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize, n-gram, elasticsearch-analyzers

I've got an Elasticsearch index where I've set `"max_ngram_diff": 50`, but somehow it seems only to be working for the `edge_ngram` tokenizer but not for the `ngram` tokenizer.

I've made this two requests against the same URL `http://localhost:9201/index-name/_analyze`:

**Request 1**

```
{
    "tokenizer":
    {
        "type": "edge_ngram",
        "min_gram": 3,
        "max_gram": 20,
        "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
        ]
    },
    "text": "1234567890;abcdefghijklmn;"
}
```

**Request 2**

```
{
    "tokenizer": {
        "type": "ngram",
        "min_gram": 3,
        "max_gram": 20,
        "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
        ]
    },
    "text": "1234567890;abcdefghijklmn;"
}
```

The first request returns the expected result:

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "123",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 3,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "1234",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "12345",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 5,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "token": "123456",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 6,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 3
        }, 
        // more tokens
    ]
}
```

But the second request only returns this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "remote_transport_exception",
                "reason": "[ffe18f1a89e6][172.18.0.3:9300][indices:admin/analyze[s]]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "The difference between max_gram and min_gram in NGram Tokenizer must be less than or equal to: [1] but was [17]. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_ngram_diff] index level setting."
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

What happened, that the first request with the `edge_ngram` tokenizer can have a bigger difference between `max_gram` and `min_gram` than `1`, but the second request with the `ngram` tokenizer can't?

This is my mapping:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "max_ngram_diff": 50,
            // further settings
         }
     }
}
```

The used elastisearch version is `7.2.0`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I just used ur samples with ES 7.5 and it works perfectly fine for me and IMO there is no breaking or recent changes in this behaviour

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is related to the ES version 7.2.0. Everything works as expected when using ES version 7.4.0.